# How to develop Overlays in Qt?

Tags: qt, opengl, overlay

I'm looking to build Image Overlays in Qt. Considering the following image.

[image: Sample Image with Overlay]

How do I attach an overlay layer(text/non-text), on any widgets in the QApplication. In the above image, the exclamatory mark is an example of an image overlay on an image. Does Qt have any support for developing systems like these?

Comment: Inherit from the widget, override its `onPaint` method, forward it to the parent class to let it draw his stuff and then draw your own.

Comment: The image is placed in the parent widget, and does not have a widget for it's own. Should we create a widget for the image? Else, does Qt allows me to operate on the image directly?

Comment: *Some* widget is drawing that image, no? Inherit from that and do your own drawing over the image. You can of course also modify the image directly - you can create a `QPainter` over a `QImage` and draw over it however you like.